# Why is this line choking my jQuery dataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a [jQuery dataTable](http://datatables.net) coded up like so:

```
$("#my-datatable").dataTable( {
    "bProcessing" : true,
    // Commenting out next line
    //"sDom" : 't',
    "sAjaxSource" : "some/url/on/my/server",
    "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
    "bDestroy" : true,
    "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        aoData.push({
            "name" : "asking",
            "value" : "yes"
        });

        request = $.ajax({
            "dataType" : "json",
            "type" : "GET",
            "url" : sSource,
            "data" : aoData,
            "success" : fnCallback
        });
    },

    "aoColumns" : [
        {
            "mDataProp" : "name"
        },
        {
            "mDataProp" : "expr"
        },
        {
            "mDataProp" : "seq"
        }
    ]
});
```

Notice the line that commented out. When this code runs as-is, the table renders beautifully. Unfortunately, it displays lots of stuff that I **don't want** displayed, such as pagination information, a search bar, etc.

After reading the docs and following the examples, I'm convinced that the line that is commented-out is what I need to configure the dataTable so that only the table itself renders/displays.

But, when I comment it out, I get an error in Firebug and no data populates my table:

```
TypeError: an is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

for ( var i=0, iLen=an.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
```

It seems too be complaining about `jQuery.dataTables.js` line 2895. Can anybody spot why this is happening? Is my `sDom` attribute not configured correctly? Remember, I just want the table and its headers to draw (and all the data in it). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is this perhaps

http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html

you could leave sDom: T (the default) and manually turn everything off

```
            "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false
```

Comment: Just a note, I ended up needing to leave `sDom` commented out, otherwise my dataTable was still throwing the same error. Thanks for the help @Ricky.G

Answer (score 3):

When setting `"bProcessing": true`, you have to make sure the `'r'` is defined inside the `sDom`, otherwise the error will be generated.

Example :

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 4, 5 ] }],  
    "sDom": "t<'row-fluid'<'span4'i><'span8'pP>r>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {  "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"    }
});
```